# Method-scoped instance variable

Tags: c#, scope

I occasionally find myself in a situation where I have a variable that will only ever be used by one method in a class. Currently I use an instance variable, but it seems like bad design to have this variable visible to the rest of the class. Example just to illustrate a situation where I want this:

```
private Window _Window;
private void Show()
{
    if (_Window == null)
    {
        _Window = new Window();
        _Window.Closed += delegate { _Window = null; };
        _Window.Show();
    }
    _Window.BringIntoView();
}
```

The instance variable only exists to prevent more than one window being created at a time, so there's no reason for the rest of the class to know about it. I'm reminded of C++'s ability to define static variables within a function.

Is there any way to achieve something like this is C#? Or am I stuck with the decision of choosing between bad design and bad encapsulation? (Assuming that this method truly doesn't warrant a class of its own.)

Comment: Looks like the answer is [no](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/05/11/why-doesn-t-c-support-static-method-variables.aspx).

Comment: In terms of design, could you not use a Singleton to ensure that only one instance of the window is ever created?

Comment: Yes, perhaps in this scenario it could be appropriate, but my example was meant to be more illustrative than a specific problem I was looking to solve.

Comment: C/C++ has "static variables" which can be used for this purpose. A static variable local to a function leads to initialization on first call (in effect but not sure if the initialization happens earlier) and on every subsequent calls the previous values is preserved.

Comment: Even ES6 generator functions can be thought of as providing method-local variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve something like this is C#?

No.

> Or am I stuck with the decision of choosing between bad design and bad encapsulation? (Assuming that this method truly doesn't warrant a class of its own.)

Well, I'm not sure you're actually stuck with either of those. It sounds like this is part of the state of the object, even if none of the other methods need to refer to that aspect of its state. Would it be *logically wrong* for other code within the same class to refer to this aspect of state? If so, why?

(Admittedly I've occasionally wished for the ability to declare a field "within" a property declaration, forcing the rest of the class to access the state via the property...)

Comment: I suppose it's not wrong. Even in my example, the window truly is owned by the entire class that creates it. Just trying keep my code clean and avoid as much unnecessary state/accessibility as possible.

Comment: @ceykooo: I feel your pain probably more than my answer implies, but equally I think it's good to make it clear that all of the state of an object really is associated with that object. I don't like the idea of "secret" state which looks disconnected from the rest. Maybe what would be nicer would be a way of declaring an instance field as normal, but decorating it somehow to say "only usable via members X, Y and Z".

Comment: @JonSkeet: Making an instance variable "secret" or super private (http://www.headspring.com/patrick/public-private-super-private/ -- not exactly the same thing) could be a good thing. Granted, methods are not where we look for state now but placing a variable in a method could imply that it is not used for anything like serialization (true for super private variables where I have wanted them). Super private offers more of the organizational expressiveness that makes OO development popular in the first place. Microsoft/Oracle, you listening?

Comment: @Hydropteryx: There are other ways of making sure a field isn't serialized. I'm still opposed to making this part of the language.

Comment: @JonSkeet The important part is that super private offers more of the organizational expressiveness that makes OO development popular in the first place. Saying that all of the object state should be defined at the object level does not make sense when all of the application state should never be at the application level. That is the purpose of object, to ensure SoC. Method private / super private provide further decoupling of code within a class and are therefore good.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to achieve something like this is C#?

No, unfortunately, C# does not have the ability to define a class level variable scoped to a method.

As a side note, Visual Basic does allow this via the [Static modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx).  This causes the compiler to create a (decorated) class level variable, but the language will only allow it to be used within the Sub or Function in which its defined.  Other languages will see it as a member variable, however.

Comment: Very interesting. Add that onto the list of language features in VB that I wish were in C#. (Currently topped by auto-property default values.)

Answer (score 1):

The only approach known to me is worse than the clutter you are trying to avoid.

```
// Constructor
public MyClass()
{
    {
        // _Window is private to this closure
        Window _Window;
        Show = () =>
        {
            if (_Window == null)
            {
                _Window = new Window();
                _Window.Closed += delegate { _Window = null; };
                _Window.Show();
            }
            _Window.BringIntoView();
        };
    }
}

// Replaces Show method
private Action Show;
```

Then use Show.Invoke() instead of Show(). There are however places where this approach is better: http://www.headspring.com/patrick/public-private-super-private/. However, in my opinion, method private should be in C# / Java.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to let the window class itself keep a static reference to an instance of itself. You would also expose a static method `Display()` in the window class, letting the window class handle the creation and disposal of instances. Basically you would have to move your code into your windows's class.

```
private static DisplayWindow _window;

public static void Display()
{
    if (_window == null)
    {
        _window = new DisplayWindow();
        _window.Closed += delegate { _window = null; };
        _window.Show();
    }
    _window.BringIntoView();
}
```

In another class

```
DisplayWindow.Display(); // No variable required here!
```

---

If you want to disallow the "wild" creation of windows of this type, make the constructor of the window private

```
private DisplayWindow()
{
}
```

This forces other classes to call `Display()` if they want to open this window.